# How to get a specific section of a string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I have a varying string that follows this syntax: x-y12h-z13-1

I want to be able to just get the integer after "z" using PHP. In this example it would be 13. I am not sure the best way to figure it out and I am really bad at regex.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: The string can vary in length before and after the "z" integer value also.

Comment: $num = (int)substr($str,-4, 3) will give you 13 in this case but if the string isn't fixed and varies every time to a different length then you'll need to provide us little more information.

Comment: You should really give more samples of strings and exactly what the rules are to get a decent answer out of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
preg_match('/(?<=z)\d+/', 'x-y12h-z13-1', $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

matches one or more digits with a z in front of them. http://codepad.viper-7.com/X5mu2m

Answer (score 0):

It all depends of how "stable" the structure of your source string is. You can use `substr()` at start http://php.net/substr combined with `strstr()` http://php.net/strstr

Comment: I thought about that but the string can vary in length before and after the "z" integer value.

Comment: info that string length can change was not in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You may extract it using string functions also, here is the example:

$a = 'x-y12h-z13-1';
echo substr(strstr($a,'z'),1,strrpos(strstr($a,'z'),'-')-1);

Answer (score 0):

if "z" is really stable value
then

```
$subject = "x-y12h-z13-1";
$pattern = '/-z(\d*)-/i';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);

echo $matches[1][0];
```

if  structure is stable, then

```
$subject = "x-y12h-z13-1";
$pattern = '/^.*-.*-\w(\d*)-.*/i';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);

echo $matches[1][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

A general regular expression for your string:

```
<?php

$value = preg_match('/^x-y(\d+)h-z(\d+)-(\d+)/','x-y12h-z13-1', $matches); 
print_r($matches);
```

$matches[2] contains the value after the 'z'

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => x-y12h-z13-1
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 13
    [3] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you

```
$string = "x-y12h-z13-1";

$expl = explode("-", $string);
$str = "";   
foreach ($expl as $arr) {
    $strpos = "";
    $strpos = strstr( $arr, "z"); 

    if ($strpos) { 
        $str = substr($arr, "1",strlen($arr));
    }


}

echo $str;
```

$str will have your string output as 13.

Answer (score 0):

```
$your_integer = (int)substr($str, strpos($str, "z") + 1);
```

This finds the first z and then cuts the string off, including the z.

Then I rely on PHP's casting behaviour reading the first characters until it finds no more numbers and converts them into integer.